# Angular unit test doesn't give expected result

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am a starter of Angular unit testing with Jasmine and Karma. To test I have written a small component. My component is following:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  template: `{{ message }}`,
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.css']
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() message: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

I have the following test spes to test the above component:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { InputComponent } from './input.component';

describe('InputComponent', () => {
  let component: InputComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<InputComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ InputComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InputComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should correctly render the passed @Input value', () => {
    component.message = 'Hi there';
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.innerHTML).toBe('Hi there');
  });
});
```

This is alright, and the test gives the expected result. But when I separated my HTML in template file, the test runner gives following error:

> Expected 'Hi there ' to be 'Hi there'.

After separation, my component and template file looks like following:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.css']
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() message: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Content of my template file is:

```
{{ message }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `innerHTML` returns the string with a whitespace in the end.

> Expected 'Hi there ' to be 'Hi there'.

Check your template for a new-line or whitespace after `{{ message }}`. Many of the IDEs save the template/file with a newline at the end. that might be causing the problem.

You should be using  `{{message}}` in a span or `<p>` that way you can just get the value from the html tag in stead of getting the entire template and run into such issues.

EX:

```
   const mypara = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#myParagraph')).nativeElement as HTMLElement;

   expect(mypara.innerText).toEqual('Hi there');
```

Comment: Thanks, when I wrapped the input under a html element, its return expected result.

Answer (score 0):

> Expected 'Hi there ' to be 'Hi there'.

As you can see, there's a space character after the bound message.

It seems like there's a new-line or any other white-space character in the end of the template file.